# Is it possible to use a delegate to send a message when the event is not produced by a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, target-action

I'd like to know how to use a delegate to send a clock message to `MyViewController` from a class called `MotionListener` but am having trouble translating Apple's explanation of `target-action` into a workable command.

> Target-action is a design pattern in which an object holds the information necessary to send a message to another object when an
>   event occurs. The stored information consists of two items of data: an
>   action selector, which identifies the method to be invoked, and a
>   target, which is the object to receive the message.][1](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009071-CH3-SW1)

I have no trouble applying the explanation *(above)* in the example *(below)* with `myButton` using a delegate to send a message to a target called `fromButtonInSubview` whenever it is pressed

```
        [mySyncButton addTarget:self.delegate
                         action:@selector(fromSyncButtonInSubview:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I would assume that in order to send a signal that does not originate from a `UIButton,` I would still need to declare the protocol *[a]*, give it a property *[c]* and include an initialisation method *[b]*

*[a]*

```
    @protocol SyncDelegate <NSObject>

    -(void)fromSync:(int)clock;

    @end

    @interface MotionListener : NSObject {

    }
```

*[b]*

```
    - (id) initMotionSensingWith:(float)updateInterval;
```

*[c]*

```
    @property (assign) id<SyncDelegate> delegate;

    @end
```

and declare the protocol in the interface *[d]* and add the target method in the implementation *[e]*

*[d]*

```
    @interface PlayViewController : UIViewController <SyncDelegate>
```

*[e]*

```
    - (void)fromSync:(int)clock
    {
        NSLog(@"tick"); // do stuff and show
    }
```

then in `MyViewController,` import `MotionListener`*[f]*, declare it in the implementation *[g]* and define the delegate *[h]*

*[f]*

```
    #import "MotionListener.h"
```

*[g]*

```
    MotionListener *sync = [[MotionListener alloc] initMotionSensingWith:(float)updateInterval];
```

*[h]*

```
    sync.delegate = self;
```

But despite re-reading the explanation quoted above and after several failed attempts, I have yet to write a command that will send a sync signal from `MotionListener` to `MyViewController.` I know it will have the effect of `addTarget:self.delegate` and `action:@selector(fromSync:)` in the `UIButton` example *(above)*. And before anyone suggests `NSTimer selector,` I already clock this at 50 Hz whereas the sync signal is 1 Hz

e.g.

```
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02;  // 50 Hz
                                      target:self
                                    selector:@selector(motionRefresh:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                     repeats:YES];

    - (void)motionRefresh:(id)sender
    {
        count = (count + 1) % 50;  // every 1 second

        if (count == 0 ) 
        {
            // send the sync message here
            // EDIT
            NSLog(@"sending %i", count);
            [self.delegate fromSync:(int)count];
        }
    }
```

So my question is: using a delegate how can I send a sync message each time `count` turns `0` ? The answer is probably embarrassingly simple but I can wear that if you can help. Thanks.

Comment: This is straight protocol/delegate stuff.  No need to be concerned about UIResponder actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your code correctly. but I think you simply have to replace your `// send the sync message here` line with a call to your delegate like `[self.delegate fromSync:WHATEVERVALUEYOUWANTTOINFORMABOUT];`.

Comment: Andre, thanks. When I tried     NSLog(@"sending %i", count);
    [self.delegate fromSync:(int)count];         it indicates sending with nothing received. See the 2-line edit in code. I'm checking other settings now ...

Comment: what are you trying to say? :)

Comment: Andre, thanks, it all checks out. I accepted this as the answer.